# someone know why this query dons't work?

Tags: oracle

When I do this:

```
select distinct
       a.ano ano,
       a.mes as mes,
       count(*) as percentagem
from   (
  select substr(intfaims.f_aims_to_fecha@intfaims(nt.roster.dutyday@intfaims,0,2),5,2) as mes,
         substr(intfaims.f_aims_to_fecha@intfaims(nt.roster.dutyday@intfaims,0,2),1,4) as ano
  from   nt.roster@intfaims
  where  nt.roster.LEG_FLT@intfaims > 0
) a 
group by a.ano, a.mes
```

it works fine

but when I apply a select they doesn't:

```
select *
from   (
  select distinct
         a.ano ano,
         a.mes as mes,
         count(*) as percentagem
  from   (
    select substr(intfaims.f_aims_to_fecha@intfaims(nt.roster.dutyday@intfaims,0,2),5,2) as mes,
           substr(intfaims.f_aims_to_fecha@intfaims(nt.roster.dutyday@intfaims,0,2),1,4) as ano
    from   nt.roster@intfaims
    where  nt.roster.LEG_FLT@intfaims > 0
  ) a 
  group by a.ano, a.mes
) b
```

I get:

> ```
> Error: no es una expression group by
> ```

Comment: Why are you using `DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY` in the same query? There only be one row per group so `DISTINCT` will do nothing.

Comment: you're right. but it's not the cause of the error.

Comment: I'd guess Oracle is rewriting the query incorrectly, possibly confused by the remote references; do you see the same thing if you replace the innermost query with something local (even selecting dummy values form dual)? The execution plans might show something useful, but you might need to trace it to see what it's really doing.

Comment: Both of your queries are not fine. I think only the inline view aliased as `a`  with select distinct columns should work fine. Also you are using the dblink reference  `@`  everywhere. Use it only in one place in from clause with proper alias and re-use it in the rest of the query.

Comment: That doesn't look quite like an Oracle-generated error, as it has no code (ORA-00979) and the `group by` would normally be capitalised. Have you modified it when posting? Or is your client generating that itself? If it's coming from the client try running it in SQL\*Plus and see if that also complains.

Comment: when i use a a local databbase they just work fine, and e even though I use a alias, show-me the same error